# Convert chm file to Dash Docset

Tags: decompiling, chm

[Dash](http://kapeli.com/docsets) can provide Docset for offline use and docsets can be generated from HTML, Doxygen, etc.

Does anybody knows a way to generate a docset from a chm file?

Comment: @ngs: How about putting this into an actual answer?

Comment: [original comment]: A tool has been built by the user "ngs" to do that very thing: https://github.com/ngs/chm2docset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `chm` file can be decompiled to HTML, either with the help viewer (`hh.exe -decompile folder file.chm`) or using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). So you could generate a docset from the extracted HTML.